# "Uncaught ReferenceError: (function) is not defined" with onfocus event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scala, coffeescript

I've this input in a scala.html file of my template (I use Play Framework):

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" onfocus="isEmailExistF();" >
```

and this Coffee script:

```
  isEmailExistF = ->
    $("#email").fadeOut()
```

Then when I focus the input #email nothing happens and the console reports:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: isEmailExistF is not defined
  > onfocus
```

But it's the same if I replace `onfocus` with `onblur` or others event. CoffeeScript compilation is ok because I've other coffee scripts that work right. I tried to use plain jquery to understand if it's a Coffee issue. I put this code embedded in the code:

```
<script>
var isEmailExistF;

isEmailExistF = function() {
  return $("#email").fadeOut();
};
</script>
```

and it works. Where am I wrong?

**EDIT**:
the script file is included in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

and the content (compiled from coffeescript) is:

```
(function() {
  var isEmailExistF;
  isEmailExistF = function() {
    return $("#email").fadeOut();
  };
  $(document).ready(function() {
     ...
```

Comment: instead of this onfocus="isEmailExistF();"  replace  onfocus="isEmailExistF()". in your code u have added semicolon to the function. @Fred K

Comment: hi @DD. already tried that, it's the same

Comment: Is your function in the `<head>` and not in a `DOM ready / load` event?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It doesn't require DOM ready as the event handler is assigned inline (that's only relevant when you need to wait for an element to exist before assigning event handlers).

Comment: @Archer I know that, but if you put the function in the DOM ready event or window load or even at the bottom of the page, it will throw this error because the function isnt defined when the DOM read this tag. That's why i ask, because if those conditions arent met, that's the problem.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon If it's in a DOM ready event then it will be in a closure, so not accessible to the page, yes.  It won't matter if it's at the bottom of the page though.  I see your point now though.  I thought you were saying it should be in DOM ready, not that it shouldn't :)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon & Archer: can look at the edit? thanks

Comment: The IIFE around the compiled CoffeeScript means the function isn't available to the outside scope.

Answer (score 0):

i made this in coffeescripit page : http://coffeescript.org/

IN HTML CODE remove focus attr:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email">
```

inside coffeescript replace your code for this:

```
$(document).ready -> $(document).on("focus","#email",-> $(this).fadeOut())
```